# How to stop the rest of the code when condition is met

Tags: javascript

This is a test from Mozilla regarding running a block of code if the machine is turned on, and not running it if it is turned off. I was able to write the code for the score variables, however, I don't know how to stop the rest of the code from running if the 'machineActive' variable is 'false.

I could only find the 'break;' for switch statements. How do I do this in the if / else if/ else operators?

```
let section = document.querySelector('body');

let response;
let score = '75';
let machineActive = false;


// Add your code here


if (machineActive === false) {
    alert('Your machine is not working');
} else if (machineActive === true) {
    alert('The machine is turned on, you can play!\nClick the ok button to continue ');
}
if (score < 0 || score > 100) {
    response = 'That is not possible!';
} else if (score > 0 && score < 19) {
    response = 'That was a terrible score -- Total Fail!';
} else if (score > 20 && score < 39) {
    response = 'You know some things, but its a pretty bad score';
} else if (score > 40 && score < 69) {
    response = 'You did a passable job, not bad!';
} else if (score > 70 && score < 89) {
    response = `That's a great score, you really knew your stuff!`;
} else if (score > 90 && score <= 100) {
    response = `What an amazing score! Did you cheat? Are you really a person?`;
} else if (score != Number) {
    response = 'Input is incorrect';
} else if (score === 0 || score === null) {
    response = 'Null / Undefined';
} else {
    'Error occured';
}


// Don't edit the code below here!

section.innerHTML = ' ';
let para1 = document.createElement('p');
let para2 = document.createElement('p');

para1.textContent = `Your score is ${ score }`;
para2.textContent = response;

section.appendChild(para1);
section.appendChild(para2);
```

Comment: You could wrap the whole block in a function and return early

Comment: you gotta ```return``` something... try to add ```return response;``` below every ```response = ... ```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it? I was under the impression that I was not supposed to use a function for this problem.

Comment: The only way to halt running code that is not part of a function is to throw an error (which is not something you normally want to do).

Comment: Is it intentional that scores 0,19,20,39,40,69,70,89,90 are not met in the score conditions?

Comment: `else if (machineActive === true) {` put all other code in else if block. will work that is a simple solution. but I think you are not defining the whole problem what actually do you want

Comment: move second `}` before `if (score < 0 || score > 100) {` to end, after `'Error occured';`, and indent everything in between.

Comment: you are mixing "`" and "'" in `scort>70...` and in `score>90...`

Comment: change all `>` to `>=`.

Comment: I didn't realize about the nesting so that fixed the problem. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this :

```
if (machineActive === false){
   //do something or don't
}
else{
   // we know that machineActive is true now
   // here you can nest your other if/else statements
}
```

Comment: That clarified my confusion. Thank you!

Comment: yes, for checking a Boolean variable, you only need if/else. you don't need 2 if's.